# Flickr API: Uploading without authentication?

Tags: image-uploading, flickr

I'm working on an application that pulls images from Flickr, and it also offers the ability to upload to Flickr. The problem is that the Flickr API doesn't seem to accept photo uploads without authentication.

In other words, end-users using my application would have to pass through the Flickr website and log in with their Flickr account and grant permissions, and only after that, Flickr starts the upload process.

After doing some searching, I've seen things like having a permanent token for the authentication and upload as since user all the time...

If anyone can offer any solutions or workarounds, please help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to be able to upload to other people's account then yes, you'll need to get a permanent authorization token. How else could it work?

Comment: @Danack Thanks for your reply. I just want people to upload to the group i created off my account at Flickr without having to require the end-users to login to their Flickr account..

Comment: Unless you're going to be uploading to your account, then you would need to have the users authorization to upload to their account. It's not too bad though, there are lots of libraries that do the auth for you - including my own at https://packagist.org/packages/intahwebz/flickrguzzle

Comment: However you should probably close this question - it isn't appropriate for stackoverflow as it's not a direct programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post regarding triple tags and pulling flickr photos into a single wordpress post: http://zedzdead.net/blog/2013/04/10/flickr-machine-tags/

The wordpress stuff is irrelevant, but tagging photos with triple or "machine" tags is ideal for associating photos across multiple accounts and extracting them using the api.

You might need to inform your app users about the tag they need to use e.g. myapp:article=123, but you can then use the search method in the flickr api and use the machine_tags argument to pull all photos on flickr with this tag.

This isn't my idea, Jeremy Kieth did it first: http://adactio.com/journal/1274/

The beauty of this approach is that no flickr authentication is required.